# Celery tasks are executed by different program binaries

Tags: django, celery, uwsgi

I have a Django web application that executes tasks via celery. It is run with a combination of Apache, uWSGI, and Redis. For some reason, one of the tasks is being executed by the uWSGI server and the other is executed by the Python interpreter. This is causing permissions issues as uWSGI doesn't run as the same user as Python does.

What could cause the tasks to be run by different programs? Is there a setting somewhere?

Comment: Your problem statement is missing some information. It's not really possible for a celery task to be run by uwsgi - the celery process is completely independent of uwsgi. There is likely some other issue with how you've set things up but we'd need more information about exactly how you've configured celery to be able to identify what the problem is.

Comment: That's what I thought too. Unfortunately I didn't write this app, so I myself am trying to figure out how it is configured. Any tips on where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I needed to call the task with `.delay()` to get the Celery deamon to execute the task instead of uWSGI.